# Need helping in building a jar using sbt ( kafka - spark streaming business case )

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-kafka

I have this dependency in my build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka_2.10" % "0.10.0-kafka-2.1.1" %
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.0" % "provided" scalaVersion := "2.10.4" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.0.0" % "provided"
```

but i am getting below error when trying to build the jar

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.kafka
#kafka-clients_2.10;0.8.2: not found
```

Comment: kafka-clients come from spark-streaming, what version of spark and spark streaming are you using ?

Comment: edited the question with updated sbt file and error message.

Comment: spark streaming used - libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.0" % "provided"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.0.0" % "provided"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong version for spark-streaming and spark-streaming-kafka. Version 1.0.0 it's too old, i don't think you have the intention to use it. Instead use newer version, at least spark 1.6.1

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "2.1.1"
```

Comment: i added the dependencies but still facing the error which i mentioned in the question. am i missing anything else.

Comment: Are you using 0.10.0-kafka-2.1.1 ?

Comment: then move all your spark version on 2.1.1. See update response. I also suggest using scala version 2.11